# Datatables : search input hidden record

Tags: jquery, datatable

Datatable contain below data format

```
<tr>
<td> DisplayedVal
<td><input type="hidden" name="val" id="val"
    value="hiddenVal"></td>
</td>
</tr>
```

want to serach only hidden values.  So when I search hiddenVal I should get that row.

Comment: you can put the hidden value in a column and tell datatable to make the visibility to false, http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible

Comment: @saravanann Is there any other way to do without adding extra column?